# How to find difference in two models which has property of own list?

Tags: c#, .net, tree

I have three models as describe below:

```
public class ComponentData //Contains list of Component Model
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public List<Component> Components { get; set; }
}

public class Component //Contains list of ComponentValue Model
{
    public Int32 SiteId { get; set; }
    public IList<ComponentValue> ComponentValues { get; set; }
}

public class ComponentValue //Contains list of it self i.e. ComponentValue Model
{       
    public String Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String DisplayName { get; set; }
    public IList<ComponentValue> ChildComponents { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have two objects old ComponentData and new ComponentData, I want to compare these two object and want to find whether new list has any new child added or any changes in existing child. How to do that?

Note : `public IList<ComponentValue> ChildComponents { get; set; }` can have multiple children in it recursively.

I tried:

```
 using (var e1 = cdOld.Components.GetEnumerator())
            using (var e2 = cdNew.Components.GetEnumerator())
            {
                while (e1.MoveNext() && e2.MoveNext())
                {
                    var item1 = e1.Current.ComponentValues;
                    var item2 = e2.Current.ComponentValues;
                    using (var i1 = item1.GetEnumerator())
                    using (var i2 = item2.GetEnumerator())
                    {
                        while (i1.MoveNext() && i2.MoveNext())
                        {
 //Here not sure how many children both list has and how to make recursive call 
                            var item11 = i1.Current;
                            var item12 = i2.Current;
                            if (item11.Id != item12.Id || item11.Name != item12.Name)
                            {
                                cvlistold.Add(item11);
                                cvlistnew.Add(item12);
                            }

                        }
                    }


                    //var firstNotSecond = item1.Except(item2).ToList();
                    //var secondNotFirst = item2.Except(item1).ToList();
                    //var v = item1.Select(a => a.Name).Intersect(item2.Select(b => b.Name)).ToList();
                    //bool c = !(!firstNotSecond.Any() && !secondNotFirst.Any());

                }
            }
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use *IEquatable* interface (or override *Equals* and *GetHashCode*):

```
public class ComponentValue : IEquatable<ComponentValue>
{
        public String Id { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public String DisplayName { get; set; }
        public IList<ComponentValue> ChildComponents { get; set; }
        public bool Equals(ComponentValue other)
        {
            return Id == other.Id && Name == other.Name;
        }
}
```

Then, check the differences:

```
bool equals = e1.SequenceEqual(e2);
```

Comment: In my case no of children not same.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar structure in one of my projects with the difference that they could've contain more element types then one so I've made some reflection code to look up and compare these :

```
public static bool Compare ( this T obj, T comparer )
{
    bool isOkay = true;
    foreach(var field in typeof(T).GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    {
        if (!isOkay) break;

        object value = field.GetValue(obj);
        object comparerValue = field.GetValue(comparer);
        Type type = field.FieldType;
        if(Type.GetTypeCode(type) != TypeCode.Object)
        {
            if(type == typeof(IList))
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < ((IList)value).Count; i++)
                {
                    isOkay = isOkay &&(bool)_GenericCompare.MakeGenericMethod(((IList)value)[i].GetType()).Invoke(((IList)value)[i], ((IList)comparerValue)[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            isOkay = isOkay && value.Equals(comparerValue);
        }
    }
    return isOkay;
}

// _GenericVompare is :
typeof(MeTypeThatHasCompareMethod).GetMethod("Compare", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
```

This is just a shortened method which I've done so you should modify this for your needs but basically it iterates through all items of `IList` typed field and `Invoke`s the same method on that items.

FYI. This method can be slow as hell on huge lists so you should implement some kind of "cache" mechanism to store `FieldInfo[]` for some types and `_GenericCompare` `MethodInfo` to speed up the process.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I will try.